# Is there any easy way to rotate an image about z axis using java without jumping into java 3d?

Tags: java, 3d, image-rotation

I want to rotate an image about the z axis using java.

I tried to search for ways to do that but it involves complex matrix manipulations and it works on 3d models and stuff. I will resort to that if there is no other way but would like to know if there are any other alternatives for this.

I simply need to rotate an image about z axis and nothing else.

**EDIT**

This is what I need exactly:

I have an image like this:

[image]

And I want to convert it to something of this sort:

[image]

I did this using processing. I need some way of doing this using java.

Comment: That's a pretty ambiguous question. Images are generally 2D with x and y coordinates. Rotating about the z axis is an expression used with 3D modelling rather than image manipulation. Do you mean rotate around a fixed point in the image (i.e. the viewer is looking down the z axis)?

Comment: Ah that makes more sense now. That's actually a skew operation in 2D image processing. I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: If you actually want to rotate the image with perspective like this, then those 3D techniques using texture images and texture coordinates mapped to polygons is exactly what you want. If you just want to kind of emulate the effect, then advanced image processing functions that can skew the image might do the trick, though you'll have to emulate the effect of rotation yourself. With 3D the startup overhead is kind of steep, but after you get through it, you get all those benefits of the hardware acceleration, the ability to tweak the projection exactly how you like, etc.

Comment: But wouldn't processing an image using 3D techniques take up more time than simple PerspectiveTransform. This I am asking is just to know the pros and cons of both the techniques. Because I remember in many other softwares that I have used, 3D rendering takes more time than 2D rendering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to rotating an image during a Swing `paint` operation, then the correct way to do this is with an `AffineTransform`.

```
Graphics2D graphic;
graphic.drawRenderedImage(image, AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(Math.PI));
```

Unfortunately `AffineTransform` does not support perspective transforms (by definition a transform is only Affine if parallel lines remain parallel). For perspective transforms you need to use the Java Advanced Imaging API which can be downloaded from Oracle's site. It has a `PerspectiveTransform` that does just what you want. Unfortunately JAI is not quite as straightforward to use as it is much more flexible.