# How to rotate the Image along y-axis?

Tags: java, swing

The code i tried is rotating the image but i want to rotate the image vertically like rotating earth at 360 degrees with 0 inclination

The code i tried is

```
 public class MainClass extends JPanel {
    static ImageIcon icon = null;
    static RotatedIcon rotate = null;
    static JLabel label = null;

    public MainClass() {
        try {
            BufferedImage wPic = ImageIO.read(this.getClass().getResource(
                    "globe.png"));
            icon = new ImageIcon(wPic);
            rotate = new RotatedIcon(icon, 180);

            label = new JLabel(rotate);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("raise exception");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        label.repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
            InterruptedException {
        MainClass mainClass = new MainClass();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        mainClass.add(label);
        frame.add(mainClass);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
            int degree = 360;

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {

                rotate.setDegrees(degree);
                degree = degree + 90;
                label.repaint();

                mainClass.repaint();

            }
        };
        Timer timer = new Timer(1000, taskPerformer);
        // timer.setRepeats(false);
        timer.start();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/rotated-icon/ Reference link of the RotatedIcon class i used. 
As Explained am able to rotate image but that is not vertically.

Comment: You should really give concrete examples of what you want to achieve, because the rotation that this class does is not around the x axis as you claim, but around the center of the icon. So what you want to achieve is quite unclear.

Comment: I mean like rotating globe vertically along y-axis keeping centre constant

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30587938/is-there-any-easy-way-to-rotate-an-image-about-z-axis-using-java-without-jumping)?

Comment: like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kki1kbmJ8x8

Comment: Tip, you can add @JBNizet (or whoever you want to reply, so they get notified, the `@` is important)

Comment: You could use JavaFX to make the desired output using the [Camera API](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/8/3d_graphics/camera.htm) and then add it to your Swing application (however I'm not 100% sure it works)

Comment: this video is showing a 3D earth, an Icon is 2D - you must have an animated gif or a couple of icons for each 'angle' you want to show.

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger  might be that is the only possible way even i think. any other way you feel better to make the viewer think that it is rotating 360 degrees 0 inclination like in video ?

Comment: Using [animated sprites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41877789/animated-sprites-with-java-swing) but that requires an image for every angle as suggested by @CarlosHeuberger, I can't think of other solution...

Comment: @Frakcool so only solution would be taking a group of icons for each angle in an arraylist ,loop it and draw image one by one by using the  drawImage  method in paintComponent method. right ?

Comment: That was my solution, but I think @camickr has another way, try it and see C:

Comment: You're going to need more then one image - [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35472233/load-a-sprites-image-in-java/35472418#35472418)

Comment: @MadProgrammer   OMG!! Thank you so much for the reference i will look in to it :)

Answer (score 1):

If you only have a flat 2D image of the world then then best you might be able to do is use the [Marquee Panel](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/04/24/marquee-panel/).

The `Marquee Panel` will allow you to scroll the image and you can set it to wrap when it reaches the end. You won't get a 3D effect buy you will scroll around the world with a flat 2D image.